# Static function to convert QList of different types to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qlist

I have a QList which contains string, int, double and date values. I want to convert the QList to a QString and return it within a QString returning function. Is there a static function I can use or what am I missing here? My current code:

```
QString Product::toString()
{
    QStringList listString;
    QString outString;

    for(int i =0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        listString << at(i)->toString();
    }
    outString = listString.join("\n");
    return outString;
}
```

Comment: How can you exactly store `string`, `int`, `double` and `date` in the *same* list? What's the type of the list?

Comment: `QVariantList` has inner function `toStringList` for example.

Comment: @peppe `QList` is of a class type and initialised to the class member variables.

Comment: IMO you haven't given enough information. Your code looks fine and I do not understand why you need some "static" thing (you didn't describe what should be static, if static method class then your requirement is silly). Start from beginning what you have exactly and what you are trying to achieve. I'm suspecting that your problem is something else and you try to solve it by making something static and you are asking us to fix your solution instead describe what relay is your problem

Comment: You need to show the declaration of the value type that you store in the `QList`. There is no function you can re-use, but it's a trivial thing to implement yourself.

Comment: "static" is misleading, Epig likely means "generic" / "stand-alone". That would be `std::transform` and an inserter. I'm am preparing an answer. Does product have `begin`and `end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- I am assuming `Product::at(int)`is returning a `Transaction`, given a previous question.
- I am also assuming OP mean "built-in" when he or she wrote"static"

The `for` can be removed using built-in functions. Some (many?) will find the new syntax less understandable, though.

```
QString Product::toString()
{
    QStringList aggregate;
    std::transform(m_transactions.begin(),
                   m_transactions.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(aggregate),
                   std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Transactions::toString), std::placeholders::_1));
                   // or : [](const Transaction& transaction){ return transaction.toString(); });

    return aggregate.join("\n");
}
```

`std::transform` will transform every `m_transactions` elements using `Transaction::toString()`, and place the results into `aggregate`.

`std::back_inserter` means "use `QStringList::push_bask` to record the results". If `QStringList` had a `resize(int)` like `QVector` does, we could have used `aggregate.begin()` instead.

The unary function is a bit tricky, as it needs to be converted into a unary function, which what `std::bind`/`std::mem_fn` is doing. If you are using C++11, you can use a lambda instead.

---

Also from the previous question, @SingerOfTheFall's remark is valid:

> I also find it a little odd to save transactions inside of products. A
>   better design would be having a separate class that could store them.

If you keep this design, `Transaction Product::at(int)` and `int Product::size()` should be renamed to make the link with `Transaction` explicit, like `getTransaction` and `getNumberOfTransactions`.